# How to convert GraphQL schema string to JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, graphql

Is there any Node.js or just JavaScript library that can take a GraphQL schema and give you JSON of it?

So something like this:

```
type Post {
  id: ID!
  title: String
  author: Author
  votes: Int
}
```

Becomes something like this:

```
{
  "type": "Post",
  "fields": {
    "id": {
      "type": "ID",
      "required": true
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

What is the standard approach for this? I found [this](https://github.com/wittydeveloper/graphql-to-json-schema#readme) but not sure that is the best example.

Comment: https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag - process AST any way you want

Comment: Are you looking for [`printIntrospectionSchema`](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/utilities/#printintrospectionschema)?

Comment: @xadm I think that's what I'm looking for for the query, how about the schema does it work too? If so you can mark that as the answer.

Comment: schema (executable) usually is a set of typdefs + resolvers ( https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/graphql-tools/ ) ... it looks like you're interested in type defs only

Comment: How do I convert the typedefs to json then using that tool? It seems to require resolvers which I don't want/need to provide.

Comment: github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag produces AST - tree structure you can traverse/filter/whatever to create target tree structure you want - `JSON.stringify` it later to get json